# Is there any way to execute a script when a number is typed into a bash shell?

Tags: bash

Basically I want to run a script when a user types a string beginning with a digit into a bash shell and hits return. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: A specific number? Any number? All numbers?

Comment: It's possible.  I have commands called 2, 3, 4, 5 in my bin directory that produce output in 2, 3, 4, 5 columns.  It's perfectly possible to have command names beginning with digits: `2u`, `4me` and such like are completely valid as command names.

Comment: You can write a menu in bash and switch on the value entered after `read choice`.

Comment: `alias 42="${HOME}/bin/myscript.sh"`... Or `ln -s "${HOME}/bin/myscript.sh" "${HOME}/bin/42"`... Or one of many other methods involving hardlinks, copies, shell functions, etc....

Comment: It's easy if it's ok to have some read-input loop running in the foreground instead of the usual implicit show-prompt-eval loop.

Comment: Any string beginning with 0-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `bash` version is at least v4.0, you can define the function  `command_not_found_handle`. This function will be called as a last resort before bash gives up trying to find a command.

The arguments to the function are precisely the command name and its arguments (i.e. `$1` is the command).

A simple example:

```
command_not_found_handle () { 
    if [[ $1 = [0-9]* ]]; then
        echo You typed the numeric command: "$1"
    else
        echo "$0: $1 not found"
        return 127
    fi
}
```

The `zsh` equivalent is `command_not_found_handler`. I don't know what might be the philosophical significance of the presence or absence of the final <kbd>r</kbd>.

You should make sure to exit the function with a return code of 127 if you cannot handle the command, because that's how `bash` and `zsh` signal an unfound command when there is not not_found handle(r).

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I guess I need to upgrade my bash. Thanks.